# Footer text in datagrid dont apply the changes in code behind

Tags: asp.net, text, datagrid, footer

I have a datagrid with a text footer, and wanted to change the text in this footer when change selection in dropdownlist, but this change is not visible on the client(browser). I've been doing some tests and if i use the databinding() method datagrid is updated, and the text is correct.

My question is how to force the table to be drawn with the new changes. I think what the databinding() method  is redrawing the datagrid, in the browser.

Comment: How are you accessing the footer?